# Javascript written in the view part of the codeIgniter is not working

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter

I have been looking for this for some time now but I don't seem to find any answer for this.
Basically, I have written a script in JS for checking the match of the password and confirm password but that script is not getting called at all, then I have written another script to close the popup using ESC key but even that does not work. I don't know where what is going wrong. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
<html>
      <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
      <meta name="Sell Punch" content="true">
      <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <title>Sell Punch Login</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/Sell_Punch/assets/css/style.css">

      <script type="text/javascript">

        function ESCclose( evt ) {
          if ( evt.keyCode == 27 ) {
              console.log( 'escape pressed' );
          }
      }
      </script>

                 <script>

          var password = document.getElementById("password"), confirm_password = document.getElementById("repassword");

      function validatePassword(){
        if(password.value != confirm_password.value) {
          confirm_password.setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
        } else {
          confirm_password.setCustomValidity('');
        }
      }

      password.onchange = validatePassword;
      confirm_password.onkeyup = validatePassword;

      </script>



      <script>


      // Get the modal
      var modal = document.getElementById('id01');

      // Get the modal
      var modal = document.getElementById('id03');


      // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
      window.onclick = function(event) {
          if (event.target == modal) {
              modal.style.display = "none";
          }
      }
      </script>

      </head>
      <body onkeydown="ESCclose(event)">

      <button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block'" class="m3">Login</button>

      <div id="id01" class="modal">
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>

      <?php echo form_open('verify1', 'class="modal-content animate"');?>

          <div class="imgcontainer">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

          </div>

          <div class="container">

        <center>
          <h1 > Login</h1>
          </center>
            <label><b>Email id</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Email id" name="email" required>

            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>

            <button class="but" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">Login</button>
          <br>
            <input type="checkbox" checked="checked">
          Remember me
          </div>

          <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
          <span align = "left"><a href="<?php echo site_url('Test/') ?>">Forgot Password?</a></span>
          <span align = "right"> New User? - <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('id03').style.display='block';document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none';"> Register Now</a>
            </span>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>



      <div id="id03" class="modal">
        <?php echo validation_errors(); ?>


      <form role="form" name="signup" method="post" class="modal-content animate" action="<?php echo site_url('verify2');?>" > 

          <div class="imgcontainer">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('id03').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>

          </div>

          <div class="container">
          <center>
            <h1 > Sign Up</h1>
            </center>
            <label><b>Name</b>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your full name" name="name" id ="name" maxlength="40" required>
            </label>

            <label><b>Email id</b></label>
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email id" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,3}$" name="email" id ="email" maxlength="70" required>
          <label><b>Mobile No</b></label>
           <input type="text" placeholder="Mobile No." pattern="[7-9]{1}[0-9]{9}" maxlength="10" name="mob" required>

            <label><b>Password</b></label>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Enter minimum 6 digit Password" pattern=".{6,}" name="password" id="password" required>
             <label><b>Confirm Password</b>
            <input type="password" placeholder="Confirm your Password" pattern=".{6,}" name="repassword" id="repassword" required>
            </label>

             <button class="but" type="submit" name="submit" id = "submit" value="submit"> Submit</button>

          <div class="container" style="background-color:#f1f1f1">
          Already registerd - <a href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';document.getElementById('id03').style.display='none';"> Login</a>
          </div>
          <?php echo form_close();?>


          </div>
        </form>
      </div>




      </body> 

    </html>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to StackOverflow. I've uploaded my code, please go through it.

Comment: @JYoThI I think the ids are unique only, it is password for one and repassword for another

Comment: what is the error in your console ?

Comment: just alert something in your script and check. alert($val);

Comment: var password and repassword is null because it's load the value before dom loading  @YadhuBabu

Comment: @YadhuBabu, If I alert something that comes.

Comment: @JYoThI, Yeah even I think that is the case the values are null, can you tell me how do I link the script part to the signup form of the code

Comment: push all you java script into inside the $(document).ready(function(){  ..//all script here });

Comment: @JYoThI, I tried this but still not working. BTW thank you for this by using this way the same script started working in a different file.

Answer (score 1):

Try including the script at last, after the form

Comment: Actually, I was doing that only and it was not working so I read it somewhere that script should be before the body in the head that's why I did it like this, but it is still not working.

Comment: password.onchange = validatePassword;

 password.onchange = validatePassword( ) ;